# HID variable not getting any info from definitions list

Tags: vb.net, hid

I am currently using the Devices .NET library and this is the quick start guide that the Developer provided(I just modified it). Here is the code:

```
    Private Shared Async Function InitializeHID() As Task
        Try
            Dim Logger = New DebugLogger()
            Dim Tracer = New DebugTracer()
            WindowsHidDeviceFactory.Register(Logger, Tracer)
            WindowsUsbDeviceFactory.Register(Logger, Tracer)
            Dim deviceDefinitions = New List(Of FilterDeviceDefinition) From {
                    New FilterDeviceDefinition With {
                        .DeviceType = DeviceType.Hid,
                        .VendorId = &H25A7,
                        .ProductId = &H2410
                    }
                }
            Dim devices = Await DeviceManager.Current.GetDevicesAsync(deviceDefinitions)
            Dim anotherDevice = devices.FirstOrDefault()
            Await anotherDevice.InitializeAsync()
            Dim buffer = New Byte(64) {}
            buffer(0) = &H3F
            buffer(1) = &H23
            buffer(2) = &H23
            Dim readBuffer = Await anotherDevice.WriteAndReadAsync(buffer)
            Debug.WriteLine("Success")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("false")
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim temp = InitializeHID()
    End Sub
```

I am running into the issue where the devices variable is getting nothing so therefore it just writes false instead of sending the bytes and writing success.

Please help!